# Downloading transaction history from PayPal

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to transfer and process PayPal transactions made on the web to another web-based system we use for tracking our sales history.

While it may seem like an easy and common problem, I'm striking out on an approach to accomplishing this.

- IPNs are not an option (long story, trust me)
- Apparently the REST API only lets you download transactions created by the REST API but not ones that originated from a web page (seems pretty silly)
- Reviewing the "classic" APIs I see a bunch of interfaces but none focused on downloading transaction histories.

So - the big question is - what's the best way to download transaction histories?

Answer (score 0):

If their API doesn't offer the data you want, you have to automate the browsing and scraping task. I suggest Selenium and/or Python requests + lxml.